# How is implemented this function foo.getSize().x

Tags: c++, syntax, sfml

Recently I've start learning sfml graphics and I saw this kind of functions window.getSize().x or .y, my question is how can I write such a function, more exactly to use .x or .y on an object function?

Comment: The code for `SFML` is fully open source meaning you can see the implementation. [https://github.com/SFML/SFML](https://github.com/SFML/SFML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions return a vector object that have the variables x and y internally.

Something kinda like this

```
template<typename T>
struct Vec2
{
    T x, y;

    Vec2(T x, T y)
        : x(x), y(y)
};

class Window
{
public:
    Vec2<unsigned int> getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
private:
    Vec2<unsigned int> size;
};
```

This is only a simple example but it should show you how it works.

Answer (score 2):

> to use .x or .y on an object function?

This seems to indicate a misunderstanding of the syntax. The `.x` and `.y` are not being applied to the function. Rather, they are applied to the value returned by the function.

In this case, `sf::Window::getSize()` returns a `sf::Vector2u`. The `sf::Vector2u` class has two public attributes, `x` and `y`. Writing

```
unsigned value = window.getSize().x;
```

is (concise and) equivalent to writing (more verbosely)

```
sf::Vector2u size = window.getSize();
unsigned value = size.x;
```

The function does not define `.x`; the class does.